# Node Metatag data migration with the Migrate-Update\Drupal-Upgrade module

Tags: 8, migrations, meta-tags

I ask this for freshmen like myself, and others, who want to make sure they are making the best migrate-update possible:

I have created a local copy of a Drupal 7 site and have also created a brand-new Drupal 8 site. I have no content to migrate-update into the Drupal 8 site besides Nodes, their Metatag data, and a list of Redirects. I've already installed the modules [Migrate update](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade), [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag), and [Redirect (via GitHub)](https://github.com/md-systems/redirect) in the Drupal 8 site as well.

Is here something special that needs to be configured after the installation and enabling of the module in the Drupal 8 site to which I plan to migrate and upgrade content?

In other words, should I configure something in the D8 site Metatag module settings to insure a stable and correct migration of each node's meta title, description, and keywords from the D7 site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both redirect and Metatag have to provide their own migrations (migration templates), it's not something that you can just configure.

All you can do, if you don't know how to do it yourself is open issues for those projects and hope someone will do it. Or find someone you can pay that does it for you.

Comment: Berdir, can you please edit the question and explain what are these migration templates? Do you mean it can only be done via Migrate update and cannot be copied separately?

Comment: @benos I might be wrong, but I think the point of Berdir's second paragraph is that the templates don't currently exist. You need to code them yourself, or get someone else to code them. Probably not a trivial task, and probably not something that's going to fit in an answer here. Again though, might be wrong

Comment: Everything you need to know about what migration templates are is here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2527568.

Comment: @Clive is absolutely right. This is a development task that needs to happen, not something that can be answered away here.

Comment: I just want to comment this: Is is true to say that from the day Drupal rose up, there wasn't a free-for-all way to migrate Node metadata, and redirects? Both metadata and redirects are important for SEO, so it's hard for me to understand how this has never been part of any migrate module or plan for the sake of all users. Am I correct @Berdir ? Or I'm having a terrible mistake in that conclusion?

Comment: *Nothing* that is not in core has a migration path out of the box. Every single module that has data needs to provide a migration path itself. In fact, not even a fair amount of things that are, like views. As it was mentioned in another issue, the migration is experimental and still in development.

Comment: We also need to do Metatags migration in our project and exploring the ways to do it. Any pointers will be helpful?